# Laravel Ajax Patch not working

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel-4

Trying to figure out how to patch with ajax. I want the ajax to patch "something" when I press the btnUpdate button.

In my router:

```
 Route::patch('forecasts/edit/{id}',['as'=>'forecasts.edit',
                       'uses'=>'forecastsController@handleEdit']);
```

In my controller:

```
    public
            function handleEdit($id)
    //handle edit form submission
        {

        $data=Input::all(); 
        return $data; //just want  to see something
        }
```

In my view html:

```
<div>
   <button type='button'id="btnUpdate" name="btnUpdate">Update</button>
</div>
```

In my view script:

```
$("#btnUpdate").click(function () {
$.ajax({
           type: "PATCH",
           url : base_url+'/forecasts/edit/'+forecast_id,                    
           data :  "Something",  success: function (data) {
           alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

your ajax url seem to be wrong. Try to use helper function like route.

```
$.ajax({
           url : "{{route('forecasts.edit',forecast_id)}}",                    
        }
    });
});
```

Url Pattern for edit would be like htt://base_url/somefunction/{id}/edit

Comment: This gives me ErrorException (E_UNKNOWN) Use of undefined constant forecast_id - assumed 'forecast_id'

Comment: `base_url+'/forecasts/edit/'+forecast_id` i get this from your mentioned var.